# Создание QR кода через API

Tags: node.js, qrcode, qr

Решил я как-то раз научиться создавать красочные и красивые QR коды. Нашёл апишку, которая принимает в себя набор параметров, отправляется запрос и получается картинка. Но прикол в том, что я не понимаю как записать эту data в файл на Node. Код, что выдает и что делает я скину ниже.
Ссылка на API: https://www.qr-code-generator.com/qr-code-api/
Объект на вход:

```
const QR_CODE_DATA = {
    "frame_name": "no-frame",
    "qr_code_text": "Hello, QR!",
    "image_format": "PNG",
    "image_width": 500,
    "background_color": "#fafafa",
    "foreground_color": "#fa6e79",
    "marker_right_inner_color": "#2d7cda",
    "marker_right_outer_color": "#00bfff",
    "marker_left_inner_color": "#2d7cda",
    "marker_left_outer_color": "#00bfff",
    "marker_bottom_inner_color": "#2d7cda",
    "marker_bottom_outer_color": "#00bfff",
    "marker_left_template": "version13",
    "marker_right_template": "version13",
    "marker_bottom_template": "version13",
}
```

Если оставить image_format: "PNG", то он выдает:
[image: То, что выдает при PNG]

И я не понимаю, как записать это в виде картинки, так как в Postman он выдает картинку при тех же параметрах:
[image: Qr code из postman]

Вот код которым я пытался записать (вместо ACCESS_TOKEN нормальный токен, просто убрал):

```
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Объект который я в Postman передавал
const QR_CODE_DATA = {
    "frame_name": "no-frame",
    "qr_code_text": "Hello, QR!",
    "image_format": "PNG",
    "image_width": 500,
    "background_color": "#fafafa",
    "foreground_color": "#fa6e79",
    "marker_right_inner_color": "#2d7cda",
    "marker_right_outer_color": "#00bfff",
    "marker_left_inner_color": "#2d7cda",
    "marker_left_outer_color": "#00bfff",
    "marker_bottom_inner_color": "#2d7cda",
    "marker_bottom_outer_color": "#00bfff",
    "marker_left_template": "version13",
    "marker_right_template": "version13",
    "marker_bottom_template": "version13",
}
const QR_TOKEN = 'ACCESS_TOKEN';
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    request.post({
        url: `https://api.qr-code-generator.com/v1/create?access-token=${QR_TOKEN}`,
        json: true,
        body: QR_CODE_DATA
    }, (error, response, data) => {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        fs.writeFile('qr.png', data, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Data add');
        });
    });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Надеюсь на помощь, потому что весь инет перерыл. И не понимаю что не так.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#streaming

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bwip-js

Comment: @nörbörnën так он же генерирует штрих код